# Novel of an interstellar traveller returning to a post-plague Earth

Tags: story-identification, novel

A man returns to Earth after leading an interstellar trip with a small crew. He left a twin back on Earth. During their absence, a plague killed most of the older folks on Earth, and the remaining population was super-intelligent.

I think it was set in Australia. I think it was in the early 1980s that I saw this book in the shop and just skimmed the first chapter or so before putting it back. Couldn't find it or recall the title later.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was the twin still alive?  Did the crew count as "older folk" when they returned?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: I think the cover had a man's headshot with spacy graphics above, early 1980s style. Didn't read far enough to get what happened with the twin and the other crew. The man wasn't qualified to lead the mission, but was made captain as an excuse to put him on the trip, as part of an experiment in separating twins. The doctor on the crew had the secret task of observing him for the study.